# Method as default parameter for a method

Tags: c++, methods, template-classes

I'm currently working on a Set-class for a c++ course which is a derivation from `vector<T>`.

At a point I came to the point where I needed to implement a function called `index()` which will obviously return (if the set contains it) the index of a object within these set.
While writing the whole class I came to the point where I need to overload these `index()` method, which where both public.
So here are my two types of methods:
1st. with 3 params:

```
size_t index ( T const& x,size_t const& l, size_t const& r) const
{

    if(l > size()||r>size())
        throw("Menge::index(): index out of range.");

    //cut the interval
    size_t m = (l+r)/2;

    // x was found
    if( x == (*this)[m])
        return m;

    // x can't be found
    if( l==m)
        return NPOS;

    //rekursive part
    if( x < (*this)[m])
        return index(l,m,x);

    return index(m+1,r,x);

}
```

2nd with one param:

```
bool contains ( T const& elem ) const{
    return index(elem, 0, size()-1)!=NPOS;
}
```

The point is I don't want to write these 2 methods, it could be combined into one, if possible. I thought about default values for the `index()` method, so I would write the method-head like:

```
size_t index (T const& x, size_t const& l=0, size_t const& r=size()-1)const;
```

which gave me the error:
`Elementfunction can't be called without a object`

After thinking about that error, I've tried to edit it into:

```
size_t index (T const& x, size_t const& l=0, size_t const& r=this->size()-1)const;
```

But that gave me the error: `You're not allowed to call >>this<< in that context.`

Maybe I missed a thing, but please let me know if anyone of you can tell me either it is possible to call a method as a default param, or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not able to use `this` when defining default arguments.

> The this pointer is not allowed in default arguments [source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_arguments).

The usual way is to achieve this is to provide an overload with fewer arguments, which amounts to the initial situation you were avoiding.

```
size_t index ( T const& x,size_t const& l, size_t const& r) const;
size_t index ( T const& x ) const {
    index( x, 0, size() - 1 );
}
```

Alternatively, you can consider assigning a magic number as a default argument, which you can test against in your implementation.

```
#include <limits>

constexpr size_t magic_number = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();

size_t index ( T const & x, size_t l = 0, size_t r = magic_number) const
{
    if(r == magic_number) {
        r = size() - 1;
    }

    // Actual implementation
}
```

Comment: *Default parameter values must be compile time constants.* Not true. See http://ideone.com/PWFFHS.

Comment: @RSahu so there's no way to do that?

Comment: @PhilippZettl, there is no way to do what?

Comment: giving a method an other method as default paramter